# C# For Loop with LIST using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, list, for-loop

I'm using LINQ and returning a list to my Business Logic Layer. I'mtrying to change one of the values in the list (changing the 'star' rating to an image with the number of stars).

Although the counter (i) appears to be working, the FOR loop is not working correctly.  The first time through it stops at the correct IF but then it pops out at the ELSE statement for everything and all values end up with "star0.png."  It appears as though I'm not cycling through the list???  Thanks in advance!

```
    for (int i = 0; i < ReviewList.Count; i++)
    {
        string serviceCode = ReviewList[i].SERVICE.SERVICE_DESC;
        if (serviceCode == "*")
        {
            ReviewList[i].SERVICE.SERVICE_DESC = "star1.png";
        }
        else if (serviceCode == "**")
        {
            ReviewList[i].SERVICE.SERVICE_DESC = "star2.png";
        }
        else if (serviceCode == "***")
        {
            ReviewList[i].SERVICE.SERVICE_DESC = "star3.png";
        }
        else if (serviceCode == "****")
        {
            ReviewList[i].SERVICE.SERVICE_DESC = "star4.png";
        }
        else
        {
            ReviewList[i].SERVICE.SERVICE_DESC = "star0.png";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try using a foreach item in list loop?

Comment: The loop itself looks right to me. What happens when you step through this in the debugger? What are the values of the `serviceCode`s?

Comment: Have you confirmed the contents of `ReviewList`?

Comment: Sounds like perhaps a shared reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think its an issue of the `for loop` working properly... your syntax is good and as written will iterate `ReviewList.Count` # of times.

I would step through and verify the contents of `ReviewList` first.

Let me know what you find

Comment: So here's what I did. (1) changed serviceCode to an Integer and the value it compares is the Identity value of the table.  So if SERVICe_ID = 1, REVIEWLIST[I].SERVICE.SERVICE_DESC = star1.png.  it works perfectly.  Since I'm able to pull SERVICE.SERVICE_DESC in the UI, I don't understand why it wouldn't work in my Bus Logic Layer.  Any ideas??? Oh well,  Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: tough to say without looking at the code entirely... though i gather from the comments that you have resolved your issue which is a good thing :)

Answer (score 3):

If **all values** end up at `star0.png`, then you *are* cycling through the list. The fact that the `else` statement is the only code being executed for each element suggests a logical error -- did you perhaps mean to do something like this?

```
string serviceCode = ReviewList[i].SERVICE.SERVICE_CODE;
```

Comment: That was my reaction too... "all values" means cycling through the loop does work.

Comment: The only difference that I notice in your code is that you have replaced SERVICE.SERVICE_DESC with SERVICE.SERVICE_CODE.  The latter is an integer in my table and is the Identify value in that table.

Comment: @Susan Yes, I was suggesting that maybe you meant to put `SERVICE_CODE` and instead put `SERVICE_DESC` -- based on your comment, however, this is clearly not the case. If you add a breakpoint within your `else` statement, what are some of the values of `serviceCode`?

Comment: Thanks for the help.  If you looke at Answer 0, you can see how I finally made it work which was partially a result of both your suggestion and the suggestion above.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you know each item will consist of a number of stars, why not do this?:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ReviewList.Count; i++)
{
    string serviceCode = ReviewList[i].SERVICE.SERVICE_DESC;
    ReviewList[i].SERVICE.SERVICE_DESC = "star" + serviceCode.Length + ".png";
}
```

Comment: In theory that doesn't account for the `else` fully (though it may in practice.)

Comment: you'd need some sort or check that every element of the string is a * symbol, and a check of the length to make sure there arn't more than 4

Answer (score 0):

Protection on double pass and with else condition

```
for (int i = 0; i < ReviewList.Count; i++)
{
    string serviceCode = ReviewList[i].SERVICE.SERVICE_DESC;
    if(!serviceCode.Contains(".png")) { // once name set should not be modified
      if(serviceCode.Contains("*")) 
         ReviewList[i].SERVICE.SERVICE_DESC = "star" + serviceCode.Length + ".png";
      else
         ReviewList[i].SERVICE.SERVICE_DESC = "star0.png";

   }
}
```

alternate LINQ approach

```
       ReviewList.ForEach(rs=>if(!rs.SERVICE.SERVICE_DESC.Contains(".png"))
{ rs.SERVICE.SERVICE_DESC = 
    "star" + rs.SERVICE.SERVICE_DESC.Length + ".png"});
```